# TCP socket connection interference on send message in Kubernetes

Tags: c, sockets, kubernetes

I'm creating an application in C that intermediates and manages scheduled applications (NodeJs) to collect information into MongoDB.

This makes possible the application's scalability and avoids replicated values.

**Problem**

- Local tests: OK
- Container tests: Ok
- K8s Minikube tests: scheduled application error in bson parse
- EKS Production tests: scheduled application error in bson parse

**Code of C application to send socket message:**

```c
static void
ssq_connection_server_handler()
{
    ...

    for (i = 0; i < ssq_max_sockets; i++) {
        sd = ssq_connection->clients[i];
        if (FD_ISSET(sd, &master)) {
            if ((ret = ssq_connection->recv(sd, buffer, SSQ_SERVER_MAX_BUFFER_SIZE)) <= 0) {
                continue;
            }

            buffer[ret] = '\0';
            token = ssq_strtok(buffer, ":");
            opts = ssq_strtok(NULL, ":");

            limit = ssq_atoi(opts, ssq_strlen(opts));
            if (limit == SSQ_ERROR) {
                limit = 10;
            }

            if (ssq_strcmp("next", token) == 0) {
                u_char *tasks;
                size_t len;

                tasks = ssq_mongo_collection_find(limit, ssq_mongo->collection, &len);
                ssq_connection->send(sd, tasks, len);
            }
        }
    }

    ...
}

static ssize_t
ssq_connection_send_handler(int fd, u_char *buf, size_t size)
{
    ssize_t n;
    ssq_err_t err;

    for (;;) {
        n = send(fd, buf, size, 0);

        ssq_log_debug("send: fd:%d %z of %uz", fd, n, size);

        if (n > 0) {
            return n;
        }

        err = ssq_socket_errno;

        if (n == 0) {
            ssq_log_error(SSQ_LOG_ALERT, err, "send() returned zero");
            return n;
        }

        if (err == SSQ_EAGAIN || err == SSQ_EINTR) {
            ssq_log_debug_error(err, "send() not ready");

            if (err == SSQ_EAGAIN) {
                return SSQ_AGAIN;
            }
        } else {
            return SSQ_ERROR;
        }
    }
}
```

**Code in NodeJs to receive message:**

```js
const net = require('net');
const { EJSON } = require('bson');

const sock = new net.Socket();

sock.connect(process.env.SSQ_PORT || 3145, process.env.SSQ_HOST || '127.0.0.1', () => {
    console.log('socket connection established');
});

sock.on('data', (data) => {
    try {
        const tasks = EJSON.parse(data);
        console.log(tasks);
        process.exit(0);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        process.exit(1);
    }
});

sock.on('error', () => {
    /* void */
});

sock.on('close', () => {
    console.warn('socket connection has been closed');
});

sock.write(Buffer.from('next:10'));
```

I think that something coming from K8s is intercepting and modifying the message.

Comment: What's the workflow of your app? What makes you think it's K8s and not your C application modifying messages?

Comment: Tested  for one day in local ambiente (1M request processed) Ok, tested for one day in docker container (1M request processed) OK, tested in kubernetes (minikube) Error, tested in EKS cluster Error

Note: used the same image in docker containers for kubernetes

Comment: do you have any logs in the pod? container? when you're running in K8s?

Comment: no abnormal errors in pod logs

Comment: You need to provide more debug info. It's hard to tell, based on just saying it doesn't work